# find a video file in memory dump of a process

Tags: security, encryption, video, reverse-engineering, memory-dump

I have a player that plays encrypted video files and works like this:

1. I open an encrypted video file with it
2. it decrypts the video file and writes it to its memory
3. and plays the file from the memory after that

and I want to copy the decrypted video file from memory and play it with a usual video player like VLC so I tried to create its memory dump with task manager and hoped to find out the video file there. Sadly I don't know enough to find a video file in a large chunk of bits from memory. I tried to find mp4 patterns in a hex editor and done every solution that I find online but nothing worked for me so I hoped someone here maybe has an idea and willing to help me how to make it done.

I upload its memory dump [here](https://ufile.io/aivq3d8e) (after opening a short encrypted video with it)

Comment: `I tried to find mp4 patterns in a hex editor` There's no guarantee it's an `.mp4` video, it could be `.avi` or some other video format. Also how do you know this is encrypted and really not just a custom-made video format? Share link to the video. Maybe it's data is more obvious to extract. Got any other info like video width, height, duration?

Comment: @VC.One I guessed it might be mp4 because of the unencrypted sample files that they provide before purchase and many mp4 occurrences in the memory dump. I don't have any information about the video and the main reason that I want to unlock it is that their player doesn't provide the features that I need (for example keyboard shortcut and fast forward). I upload the players here: https://ufile.io/jucf2fpc and one of their encrypted video here: https://ufile.io/8oqiyxei, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @VC.One they use a product from a company named Copy Protection International LTD (https://www.copyprotection.net) and the product that they use to encrypt videos is https://www.copyprotection.net/balas-soft-lock.aspx. I tried to disassemble the player but couldn't find a way, just enough information to find out about the company.

Comment: I will check the files soon. I saw LAV Audio and Balas Codec listed in the hex editor and also what looked like raw RGB pixel data. Could have been a decoded video frame but for that you'd need to know the resolution (WxH) to read correct bytes amount. That's why I wondered what goes on...

Comment: @VC.One thanks a lot :) their software doesn't provide any information about the video, but from their unencrypted sample files, it might be 1280x720 and the duration of video file that is inside the memory dump and I uploaded its original file above, is 13 minutes and 26 seconds.

Comment: @VC.One and these two are their prerequisites before installing the player: https://cafetadris.com/upload/software/lock/prq.zip and https://cafetadris.com/upload/software/lock/lock-codec.zip (the last one is K-Lite Codec Pack). I thought it may help.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the software doesn't decode whole video file in one go, but instead in streaming fashion. This makes it impossible to catch a moment when the decoded video data is available in the memory dump.

If the player software is open source, compile it with debug symbols and run it under debugger. Otherwise, resort to reverse engineering.

Comment: after loading the video, the disk activity of the process tends to zero, and I found a direct ratio between the video file size and the amount of memory that player occupies. I'm not sure, but when I open the memory dump with a hex editor I can see a continues stream of bits that look like an unencrypted mp4 file but I don't know how to separate it. unfortunately, it's not open source and for reverse engineering part, I don't have the technical skills.

Comment: the first time player started, it performs an activation process with a serial key and after completing a form it receives an activation key and after that, it can play its encrypted videos offline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow in general, including but not limited to specifically reversing a software solution intended for digital rights management. However I would still leave an answer.

First of all, as comments suggest the topic in question is reversal of specific solution provided by a commercial provider. Ability to recover a media file from memory dump highly depends on implementation of this solution and methods the provider used to complicate the reversal. It is only the simplest and straightforward solution is easy to reverse and the more developer put in to cover traces, the harder - exponentially - is to reverse.

Even though there is a little chance to find the original file in full in memory (through memory dump analysis) it is unlikely to be possible for any media playback application, even such that does not do any decryption. Media playback is typically streaming: the data is loaded from disk, storage, network etc. as necessary for playback and not as a full download. Decryption needs to be applied to certain pieces of data needed momentarily, and then a decent DRM-enabled application would immediately erase the ephemeral clear data once it is no longer needed. That is, a memory dump would - at best - contain a ridiculously small amount of media data.

To capture/restore the original media file one would typically have to place himself as a middleman into some media streaming related process and be able to copy data as it is being streaming durign playback. A static memory dump is of little help here.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to read and respond to my question :) but as I mentioned above, after loading the video, the disk activity of the process tends to zero (even if I seek to middle or end), and I found a direct ratio between the encrypted video file size and the amount of memory that player occupies, that's why I thought video file might be in the memory dump. I just don't know if it is encrypted or not, if not how to find and extract it, if yes how to analyze and find out about its encryption method.